# How to reload Java applet in browser?

Tags: java, google-chrome, debugging, applet, opera

Opera 12.17 (Presto) and Chrome 34.0.1847.131m make a strong copy of Java applet in cache so the interactive development is almost impossible. How to reload applet at my will?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable caching applet in Java Control Panel (tab General, button Settings..., checkbox Keep temporary files on my computer., and Delete Files... button).

Second option I use is adding proper param insinde `object` tag:

```
<param name="cache_option" value="Plugin" />
<param name="cache_archive" value="myApplet.jar,someLib.jar" />
```

or in `embed` tag:

```
cache_option="Plugin"
archive="myApplet.jar,someLib.jar"
```

If you really fast make changes in applet, remember to kill java process, which is opening by browser. If you dont kill this process, applet won't reload and you'll still using the old one. Use `Process Explorer` to this:

[image: java process in browser]

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  When on-screen:

```
x:   clear classloader cache
```

Then refresh the web page in the browser.